# How to make cats.effect.Console with timeout?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I want to take input from console in 3 seconds, otherwise in timeout case return `"Timeout!"`. I wrote this function:

```scala
def withTimeout: IO[String] =
  Console[IO].readLine.timeoutTo(3.seconds, IO.pure("Timeout!"))
```

But it doesn't stop after 3 seconds, but waits any input, and only after input returns `"Timeout!"`. Is this happens because `Console` is not cancellable? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known "cantfix" issue. The underlying problem is that reading from stdin on the JVM is not interruptible and we can't really do anything about that.

My recommendation is to use [`fs2.io.stdinUtf8`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/co.fs2/fs2-docs_2.13/3.4.0/fs2/io/index.html#stdinUtf8%5BF%5B_%5D%5D(bufSize:Int)(implicitevidence$6:cats.effect.kernel.Sync%5BF%5D):fs2.Stream%5BF,String%5D) instead.

Further reading:

- https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/1793
- https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/3077